# alternative for the phrase redress your complaints

Tags: word-request

Is there any other phrase for - redress your complaints.. like this sounds too formal..
can you give a lesser formal sentence for the following one.
Don't worry I will "redress all your complaints and regrets". 
Can we use the word remove.. I can REMOVE ALL YOUR COMPLAINTS AND REGRETS..
Please suggest a better alternative..

Comment: Roopa, there are hundreds of ways and this question is off-topic. It's opinion based. However, for your concern - *remove* does not fit there and compare to that, *redress* is far better!

Comment: so please suggest any one from that hundred of ways.. I want the translation of this sentence: *veh tumhari saari shikayete aur shikvey door kardegi*.

Comment: Simply say - *"I/she/they will take care of all your concerns and complaints."*

Comment: @MaulikV - I don't see how this is off-topic; it looks like a word request to me, and we have a tag for that.

Comment: @J.R. She's asking for an alternative *phrase* and not a word. Had it been merely a *word request*, I wouldn't have voted. Instead, the OP asks whether or not she **can use** the word 'remove'. But a phrase, we all can come up with phrases.Like *We'll work on your complaints for sure*; *Your complaints will be addressed* and so on.  All in all, it's opinion based as I mentioned.

Comment: No, the O.P. is looking for a word within a phrase. "Can we use the word _remove_... Please suggest a better alternative" sounds like a word request to me. Besides, we have a [phrase request](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request) tag, too – "for questions seeking a phrase that fits a meaning."

Comment: "The users are complaining."  
"REMOVE ALL THE COMPLAINTS. NO-ONE WILL EVER KNOW."

Comment: Let them eat cake!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google to answer questions of such type. Look up google's [search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en).

By using quotes to look for an exact phrase and an asterisk as a placeholder, we may query google thus:

["we will * your complaints"](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22we%20will%20%2a%20your%20complaints%22)

This brings up such combinations like

> "we will **handle** your complaints"
>
> "we will **deal with** your complaints"
>
> "we will **take** your complaints **seriously**"
>
> "we will **resolve** your complaints"

etc.